# How to print into two files at once?

Tags: perl, printing, file, syntax-error

I'm having trouble getting this line of code to work:

```
for my $fh (FH1, FH2, FH3) { print $fh "whatever\n" }
```

I found it at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-print-to-more-than-one-file-at-once?) but it doesn't work for me.

The code I have so far is:

```
my $archive_dir = '/some/cheesy/dir/';
my ($stat_file,$stat_file2) = ($archive_dir."file1.txt",$archive_dir."file2.txt");
my ($fh1,$fh2);

for my $fh (fh1, fh2) { print $fh "whatever\n"; }
```

I'm getting "Bareword" errors on the `(fh1, fh2)` part because I'm using `strict`.  I also noticed they were missing a `;` in the example, so I'm guessing there might be some more errors aside from that.

What's the correct syntax for printing to two files at once?

Comment: try `for my $fh ( \*FH1, \*FH2, \*FH3) { ... }` or `for my $fh ( \*{FH1}{IO}, \*{FH2}{IO}, \*{FH3]{IO}) { ... }`

Comment: [perldoc -f filenhandle indirectly](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-a-filehandle-indirectly%3f)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You haven't opened the files.

```
my ($fh1,$fh2);
open($fh1, ">", $stat_file) or die "Couldn't open $stat_file: $!";
open($fh2, ">", $stat_file2) or die "Couldn't open $stat_file2: $!";

for my $fh ($fh1, $fh2) { print $fh "whatever\n"; }
```

Notice that I'm *not* using barewords. In the olden days, you would have used:

```
open(FH1, ">$stat_file");
...
for my $fh (FH1, FH2) { print $fh "whatever\n"; }
```

but the modern approach is the former.

Comment: Just for the record, the bareword errors are because the OP used `fh1` and `fh2` instead of `$fh1` and `$fh2` - and presumably would've opened them as `open(fh1, ...)` if copying from an example that used barewords.

Comment: i didn't open the files... when does the stupidity end?  i also needed the `($fh1,$fh2)` part corrected so `thanks++`

Comment: I believe you mean `for my $fh ( \*FH1, \*FH2 ) { ... }` or `for my $fh ( \*{FH1}{IO}, \*{FH2}{IO} ) { ... }`

Comment: @Brian - `$statfile` and `$statfile2` in the death threat section should be `$stat_file` and `$stat_file2` respectively

Comment: @CheeseConQueso Whoops - sorry. And Brad ... no, no I don't.

Comment: @Brian - Would be an improvement to include $! in the error message, to indicate *why* the file couldn't be opened.

Answer (score 7):

I would just use [IO::Tee](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Tee).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # open will now die on failure
use IO::Tee;

open my $fh1, '>', 'file1';
open FH2, '>', 'file2';

my $both = IO::Tee->new( $fh1, \*FH2 );

print {$both} 'This is file number ';

print {$fh1} 'one';
print FH2    'two';

print {$both} "\n";
print {$both} "foobar\n";

$both->close;
```

Running the above program results in:

#### file1

```
This is file number one
foobar
```

#### file2

```
This is file number two
foobar
```

I would recommend reading the whole [perldoc file](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO::Tee) for more advanced usage.

Answer (score 4):

That looks about right, it's just that it used to be common in Perl to use barewords as file handles, but nowadays it's recommended to use normal scalars.

So make sure that you actually have the files open, then just substitute the `(fh1, fh2)` part with the actual file handles (which would be `($fh1, $fh2)` or something)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open the file in order to get valid filehandles

```
open (MYFILEA, $stat_file);
open (MYFILEB, $stat_file2);
for my $fh ( \*MYFILEA, \*MYFILEB ) { print $fh "whatever\n" } 
close (MYFILEA);
close (MYFILEB);
```

Comment: you should use three argument open.

Comment: I believe you mean `for my $fh ( \*MYFILEA, \*MYFILEB ) { print $fh "whatever\n" }`

Comment: ... assuming that it is being run in strict mode, which was stated in the question. ( should have added that to my comment. )

Answer (score 0):

another version based off of Brian's answer:

```
open(my $fh1, ">", $stat_file) or die "Couldn't open $stat_file!";
open(my $fh2, ">", $stat_file2) or die "Couldn't open $stat_file2!";
for ($fh1, $fh2) { print $_ "whatever\n"; }
```