# print redirection to multiple output destinations

Tags: perl, io-redirection, filehandle

I'm looking for a way to reduce some `print` clutter in some of my scripts. I want some output to go to a file, some to the screen, and some to both. It's the "some to both" that is eluding me. Is there a way to open a *FILEHANDLE* that will go to both STDOUT and a file that is already `open`ed?

Something like this:

```
open ($file_only, ">", "$logfile");
open ($file_and_term, .....);


print $file_and_term "Nice stuff for the user to see\n";
print $file "$some_command\n";
print $file `$some_command`;   
$debug && print $file "some debug info goes here, too\n";
print "Hey, good job! You're done!\n"
```

My goal is that the lines that get sent to `$file_and_term` will not be double lines, one going to `$file` and one going to STDOUT. And also to make it more dynamic, based on debug levels, perhaps using a `select` statement controlled by the debug level.

---

So, while writing the above, I did come up with a solution that fits my needs but not my desires. :) So I'll post this Question while I implement my differently elegant solution.

---

I ended up doing this.... it's no where near as nice as a regular `print`, but I could make it more robust later....

```
sub printit {
    my ($opt, $text) = @_;
    if ($opt == $FILE || $opt == $BOTH) {print $LOG $text}
    if ($opt == $TERM || $opt == $BOTH) {print $text}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519779/perl-redirect-stdout-to-two-files

Comment: I have Perl 5.8.8. I don not have IO::Tee, File::Tee, or PerlIO:Util. Also, my script needs to work on both Unix and Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [an answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10519990/168657), you can use [`IO::Tee`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Tee) and say

```
my ($file, $file_and_term);
open $file, '>', $logfile;
$file_and_term = IO::Tee->new( $file, \*STDOUT );
```

Comment: There is actually an even earlier [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392598) that uses [IO::Tee](http://p3rl.org/IO::Tee).

Comment: I have Perl 5.8.8. I don not have IO::Tee, File::Tee, or PerlIO:Util. Also, my script needs to work on both Unix and Windows platforms.

Comment: @Stacey Robert Greenstein - then install them. [They run on practically every version and platform of Perl](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=IO-Tee+0.64).

Comment: We don't have that option. We're on a closed system. We don't get to decide what gets installed. If it's there, we can use it. If it's not, then either we can't, or there's enough red tape to make getting it not worth it.

Comment: Surely you can [copy the source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KENSHAN/IO-Tee-0.64/Tee.pm) as easily as you can copy an answer from StackOverflow.